# 15.04 to 15.10 update failure "Error during update"

Tags: updates, 15.04, update-manager, 15.10

If anyone has a clue...
The updater log follows:

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of network problem, please check your network connection and retry.

```
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80] 
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
```

**...**

can't copy the whole  log because it includes more links than I am allowed to include in a post

**...**

```
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your sources file is corrupted.

delete `sources.list` by runing this command.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

now regenerate your sources.list by opening up a terminal and typing in

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

tick all the software sources like so
[image]

Then change main server to your country then click close. then a window will pop up. click on Reload
[image]
wait for that to finish

then run the update command.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I followed your instruction but update failed as above nevertheless. I suspect something is wrong with the ARM cross-compiling stuff (binary-armhf). Possibly I will uninstall and reinstall after update.

Comment: Works perfect for Kubuntu 16.04. Just used software-properties-kde instead of software-properties-gtk and set my configuration on the 3th tab ( 'Aktualisierungen', in German) too.